# JS multiple PDF download in Chrome is limited to 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, pdf, download

I have a little script for downloading multiple pdf's on one page. The first part sets the "download" attribute, that works.

The second part iterates through every pdf on the pages and triggers a click, so it forces a download in chrome.
That also works, but instead of 30 or more pdf's it downloads only 10.

Is this a limit by js or chrome? how to allow 30 or more pdf's to download?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.order-history tbody tr').each(function(){
   var orderid = $(this).find('td:first-child a:first-child').text().trim();
   $(this).find('td:nth-child(5) a').each(function(index){
   $(this).attr('download',orderid+'-'+(index+1));
   console.log(orderid+'-'+(index+1));
   });
 }); 


  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var count=0; count<links.length; count++) {
    var url = links[count].getAttribute('href');
    if(url && url.endsWith('.pdf')) {
        links[count].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    }
}

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of simultaneous requests (including download), individually set by most of the browsers, because it would be a security issue to let a website freely download an unlimited amount of documents.

How I see it, you can only solve this directly with editing the amount of allowed simultaneous requests in the browser of the user/client.
I did not try it but this link might help you to [change the number of simultaneous downloads in Chrome](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-the-number-of-simultaneous-downloads-in-chrome) (Windows).

An indirect solution might be to pack the files which you want to download together in a ZIP file. This way you can make 30 requests to 1 request.